# How to retain a dialog's opened state onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

Say I've opened a dialog and I turn my phone sideways. I want that dialog to remain open.
How do I acheive that?

Here's what I've tried

```
Dialog dialog;
boolean dialogShown = false;

onClick:
   dialog = new Dialog(Login.this, R.style.no_title_dialog);
   dialog.show();
   dialogShown = true;

   dialogButton.onClick:
        //doStuff
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialogShown = false;
```

and then

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(dialogShown) {
        outState.putBoolean("dialogShown", true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
    outState.getBoolean("dialogShown");
    if(dialogShown){
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

but when I turn the phone sideways, I get a nullpointer Exception on row:

```
        dialog.show();
```

in onRestoreInstanceState, like it doesnt recognize the dialog anymore?

Comment: And I thought nobody uses `Dialog` anymore... Just use `DialogFragment` properly and everything will be managed for you i.e. it will stay open on orientation change etc. Consult http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: Use Activity.showDialog() or DialogFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have `dialogShown = outState.getBoolean("dialogShown")` The key parameter to `getBoolean()` can be any string, it's not a variable name.

Stylistically, the `Bundle` should be called inState in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Further, look into `DialogFragments`, this is one of the problems they're supposed to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can try put:

```
if(dialog == null) {
    dialog = new Dialog(Login.this, R.style.no_title_dialog);
}
```

before:

```
if(dialogShown){
    dialog.show();
}
```

in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Answer (score -1):

Define android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in your AndroidManifest for that activity.

Comment: and how about the forementioned operations, should I remove/tweak them, after implementing this?

Comment: using this, right now my dialog remains open, but my custom landscape layout xml is not shown, and my vertical layout is just being stretched instead?

Comment: ? can you help me out